# Associations, Models, and Controllers for a job application in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I am making a job application where the user registers and has a profile, can create companies and withing the companies jobs. To explain a bit easier, a simple LinkedIn.

- User has_one Profile (thinking of using the gem [Virtus](https://github.com/solnic/virtus) or [Cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) so user can access attribute from Profile and not using accepts_nested_attributes_for)
- User has_many Companies
- User has_many Applications to many jobs

I somewhat know how the application should be modeled but not completely sure and would appreciate some feedback and help. I will post what I think it should be and hope to get some suggestions. Thanks in advance!

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :applications
  has_many :jobs, through: :applications
  has_many :companies
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :jobs
end

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
end

class Application < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :job
end
```

Comment: looks good except for Company belongs_to :user. You cannot put one company to a single user. Company and User should be linked via jobs only and you have done it already.

Comment: @emaillenin Oh ok I will remove that line then. One thing though, I put that there because a User needs to have ownership/control over a company so User can post a job under the company. Will it still work like I intended?

Comment: yes it should work since you are posting a `Job` from user which has a relationshop already

Comment: a. You have not written "User has_many :companies", b. Maybe you should have "Company has_many :applications, through: :jobs" for association reasons, this means you will probably need company.applications, not only job.applications and user.applications

Comment: @StavrosSouvatzis a. I just added that thanks b. That makes sense will have to do a bit more reading on that, will add as well!